# Multi layout column form in Optimizely CMS

Tags: templates, content-management-system, optimizely

I am working on the Optimizely CMS trying to create multi column layout form from Display Option but having issues with the Html helper where to define it in FormContainerBlock.cshtml

How can i call this helper from Optimizely CMS.

`public static void RenderFormElements(this HtmlHelper html, int currentStepIndex, IEnumerable<IFormElement> elements)`

Comment: You need to add additional details, but this doesn't seem Optimizely-specific. The HTML helper in a Razor view would simply be invoked using `Html.RenderFormElements(...)`, just like in any ASP.NET app.

Comment: @TedNyberg I am trying to call my method like this

Optimizely_Project.Helpers.HtmlHelpers.RenderFormElements(step.i, step.value.Elements);


My method is
 public static void RenderFormElements(this IHtmlHelper html, int currentStepIndex, IEnumerable<IFormElement> elements)
 {}

it is asking for this IHtml helper method

Comment: You're not invoking it as an extension method and you're not passing the `html` argument.